# node-archiver does not work in aws lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-archiver

This code works well locally. However, it does not behave strangely in the aws lambda environment. No error occurs.
However, it does not actually work. ( lambda )
The entry and progress events of the node-archiver are not raised. What is the problem?

I can push my code to the GitHub if it's necessary.

Envirment

- node v8.10
- in Aws Lambda
- use serverless

```js
'use strict';

const axios= require('axios')
const archiver= require('archiver')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const { log } = console
const logging = value => log(value)
const errorHandler = logging

const loggingW = (value, b) => v2 => {
  if(b) console.log(value,v2)
}

const stream2 = (Bucket, Key) => {
  const stream = require('stream');
  const Body = new stream.PassThrough();
  s3.upload({
    Bucket, Key, Body,
  }, errorHandler)
  return Body
}

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: '===', secretAccessKey: '===' // ur key
})

const hello = async (event, context) => {

  const res = await axios({
    url: 'some image', // some image url
    responseType: 'stream'
  })

  const archive = archiver('zip')

  archive
    .on('entry', loggingW('a-e', true))
    .on('progress', loggingW('a-p', true))
    .on('warning', loggingW('a-w', true))
    .on('fininsh', loggingW('a-finish', true))
    .on('end', loggingW('a-end', true))
    .on('close', loggingW('a-close', true))
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('archie', err)
      throw err;
    });

  const dest = stream2('bucket', 'ttt.zip')
  dest
    .on('drain', loggingW('a-d', false))
    .on('pipe', loggingW('s-p', false))
    .on('unpipe', loggingW('s-up', false))
    .on('close', loggingW('close', false))
    .on('finish', loggingW('s-f', false))
    .on('end', loggingW('end'))
    .on('error', loggingW('error', true))

  archive.pipe(dest)
  archive.append(res.data, { name: '/ok/tt.jpg' }).finalize()

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: '1',
      input: event,
    }),
  };

  // Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY integration
  // return { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event };
};

module.exports.hello = hello

// hello()
```

Console Result

```
a-e { name: 'ok/tt.jpg',      
  type: 'file',
  date: 2019-01-30T11:31:19.255Z,
  mode: 420,
  prefix: null,
  sourcePath: null,
  stats: false,
  sourceType: 'stream',
  linkname: null,
  store: false,
  comment: '' }
a-p { entries: { total: 1, processed: 1 },
  fs: { totalBytes: 0, processedBytes: 0 } }
a-end undefined
null

// lambda
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "{\"message\":\"1\",\"input\":\"\"}"
}
```